# maven deploy plugin, only upload config file if I increment cersion number

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

When I call maven install(mvn clean install), I want to upload configuraion file to be uploeded to nexus. As repository I give nexus release repository since I could not upload configuration file to snapshot repository with maven-deploy-plugin(I am not sure, whether it is possible or not.) For, each deployment I have to increment version number, otherwise an error occurs since it could not upload same version twice to release repository. How can I manage this situation. I don't want to increment version number and upload file if I don't change the file content. I can i prevent uploading file to nexus if version number is not updated.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-file</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <file>app.properties</file>
                    <repositoryId>example.local.release</repositoryId>
                    <url>http://example.com:8000/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
                    <groupId>com.example.config</groupId>
                    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
                    <packaging>properties</packaging>
                    <version>4.0.2</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

As a summary, I would like to upload file only if its version number incremented. Also, Overwriting the file without incrementing the version number is acceptable for me.

Comment: To overwrite is a configuration option on Nexus, you can't do this with Maven.

Comment: Why not doing this in one way with the rest of the project?

Comment: @khmarbaise, what do you mean I could not understand.

Comment: @EssexBoy, do you know, could maven-deploy-plugin upload file to snapshot repositories. It is allowed to send same file again and again in snapshot repositories. But, It seems this plugin could not upload snapshot repository?

Comment: @melih.tt I dn't know, but I wouldn't do this.  Us maven the way it's intended is my advive.